# Web workers fires exception on mac safari

Tags: javascript, safari, web-worker

I am facing an below exception while I am creating a web workers. check my code snippet

```
    var temp = new Worker('/file.js')
    try{
    temp.postMessage('msg')
    }
    catch(e){
     console.error(e)
     }
```

exception is "TypeError: Value is not a sequence"

Comment: Did you solve this? ... I face the same problem.

Comment: Any fix for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how related this is, however we've encountered issues with `console.*` invocations on any Safari instance that has the WebDriver extension enabled. I suspect it has something to do with how the WebDriver collects console logs, that it somehow overrides the default implementation in a way that throws the `TypeError`.

Our solution, for unit tests, was to apply our own mocks with jasmine. A similar solution may help you.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1) {
    spyOn(console, 'log').and.stub();
    spyOn(console, 'info').and.stub();
    spyOn(console, 'warn').and.stub();
    spyOn(console, 'debug').and.stub();
    spyOn(console, 'error').and.stub();
  }
});
```